# How to insert data into ORACLE Database in ascending order using PHP for loop ?

Tags: php, oracle, for-loop, dynamic-arrays

I have these html form, jQuery and php code. So far, I managed to add dynamic fields to forms using jQuery and add the data into Oracle database.

**code.html**

```
<div id="dynamicForm">
    <button id="" class="add" name="1"> + ADD ITEM</button>
        <table id="">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>TEXT 1</th>
                    <th>TEXT 2</th>
                    <th>TEXT 3</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" class="" name="name1[]" value="" placeholder=""></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="" name="name1[]" value="" placeholder=""></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="" name="name1[]" value="" placeholder=""></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Code.js**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function formFunc(id, name)
  {
    switch(name)
    {
      case "1":
        return '<div id="dynamicFormA"><button id="" class="add" name="1">+ ADD ITEM</button><table id=""><thead><tr><th>TEXT 1</th><th>TEXT 2</th><th>TEXT 3</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td><input type="text" class="" name="name1[]" value="" placeholder=""></td><td><input type="text" class="" name="name1[]" value="" placeholder=""></td><td><input type="text" class="" name="name1[]" value="" placeholder=""></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div>';
        break;
    }
  }
  $(document).ready(function(e){
      $(".add").click(function(e){  
        e.preventDefault();
        var id   = $(this).attr('id');
        var name = $(this).attr('name'); 
        $("#dynamicForm"+id).append(formFunc(id, name));
        return false;
      });
  });
</script>
```

I manage to add the data using for loop as shown as below. I have no problem adding the data.

**Code.php**

```
<?php

    // Running no
        $sqlNextSeq         = "SELECT SEQ_TABLE.nextval AS RUNNO FROM DUAL";
        $stid2              = oci_parse($ociconn,$sqlNextSeq);
        oci_execute($stid2);
        $row                = oci_fetch_array($stid2, OCI_RETURN_NULLS); 
        $application_no     = $row["RUNNO"];
    // Running no

    // Data added
        for ( $i=0; $i<count($_POST["name1"]); $i++ ) 
        {
            if($_POST['name1'][$i] != '' || $_POST['name2'][$i] != '' || $_POST['name3'][$i] != '' )
            {
                $sql  = "INSERT INTO TABLE (
                                              ID,
                                              TEXT1,
                                              TEXT2,
                                              TEXT3
                                            )
                                      VALUES(
                                              '".$application_no."',
                                              '".$_POST["name1"][$i]."',
                                              '".$_POST["name2"][$i]."',
                                              '".$_POST["name3"][$i]."'
                                            )
                        ";
                $stid = oci_parse($ociconn,$sq);
                oci_bind_by_name($stid);
                $res  = oci_execute($stid);
                if($res){ echo "Added<br/>";} else { echo "Not added<br/>";}
            }
        }
    // Data added
?>
```

But somehow the sequence is not in order when the data added into database.

It expect the sequence will be like this

```
ID              TEXT1           TEXT2           TEXT3
1               NAME1           ADDRESS1        CONTACT1
2               NAME2           ADDRESS2        CONTACT2
3               NAME3           ADDRESS3        CONTACT3
```

But the data added like this in Oracle.

```
ID              TEXT1           TEXT2           TEXT3
3               NAME3           ADDRESS3        CONTACT3
1               NAME1           ADDRESS1        CONTACT1
2               NAME2           ADDRESS2        CONTACT2
```

Btw, here's my table, sequence and trigger

**sequence**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "DEV"."SEQ_TABLE"  MINVALUE 0 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOCACHE  NOORDER  NOCYCLE;
```

**trigger**

```
create or replace TRIGGER DEV.TRG_TABLE
 BEFORE INSERT ON DEV.TABLE FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 SELECT SEQ_TABLE.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.ID FROM DUAL;
END;
```

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The data in an Oracle table does not have any order. Unless you specify an `ORDER BY` clause in your SELECT the order of rows is undetermined (apart from a few exceptions).

Comment: You should better use [Prepared Statements](http://ch1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). They are faster and more secure in terms of security (SQL-Injection) values and quoting.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the reply. I need to sort the order by id and the select statement i forgot to add ORDER BY ID ASC. Thanks. it works now.

Answer (score 1):

your problem when your selecting the data, select it with order by id

```
select * from table order by ID asc
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply . is it inside my php code ? SELECT SEQ_TABLE.nextval AS RUNNO FROM DUAL ORDER BY ID

Comment: no not inside the sequence its correct. @Rozaimi How are you seeing the data result ? you are doing a select in the database to see them right ? in this select add order by

Comment: I'm viewing the result in the oracle database. I'm not sure why the data is not added in ascending order. no3 added first and then no1 and no3.  by default, the new data which is no3 should be at the bottom of the row list right ?

Comment: @Rozaimi it is not about the data which order is being inserted , its about how you are reading them. if you are reading the data in a select `with out order` then the data in this select will not be ordered , if you specified the order in the select then the data will be ordered , understand me ?

Comment: I see. The problem solved now. Thank you very much. :) .

Comment: @Rozaimi by definition, a heap table (which is what you get if you use the default `create table` ddl statement) stores rows in no particular order. That means that you can get rows added later that appear near the start of the table's data blocks. To guarantee rows are returned in a particular order, you must add an `order by` clause, as Moudiz has stated.